# SQL-запрос в C# для вывода из label в Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Смысл задания: при нажатии на кнопку, у меня считается разность двух чисел, записанных в лабле и текстбоксе, после чего это число должно записаться в бд ячейку таблицы access. Но он не заменяет число и ошибки в коде не показывает. В чём же может быть проблема?

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double summ;
    double raz;
    raz = Convert.ToDouble(Label7.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
    summ = Convert.ToDouble(Label2.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
    Label12.Text = raz.ToString();

    OleDbConnection conn5;
    OleDbCommand command5;

    conn5 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\andre\Desktop\kursach\Price3.mdb");
    command5 = conn5.CreateCommand();
    command5 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Price SET Количество = "+ raz +" WHERE Price.Название = 'Футболка'");

    conn5.Close();


protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double summ;
    double raz;
    double a;
    raz = Convert.ToDouble(Label7.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
    summ = Convert.ToDouble(Label2.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(TextBox1.Text);
    a = raz;

    OleDbConnection conn5;
    OleDbCommand command5;
    conn5 = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\andre\Desktop\kursach\Price3.mdb");
    command5 = conn5.CreateCommand();

    command5.Connection.Open();

    command5.CommandText = "UPDATE Price SET Количество = '"+a+"' WHERE Price.Название = 'Футболка'";

    command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn5.Close();
```

Comment: Создать команду создали, а выполнить забыли, потому ничего и не происходит

Comment: Все верно подсказали выше, перед закрытием соединения вызовите `command5.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: Если добавляю строку command5.ExecuteNonQuery();, пишет
ExecuteReader: Свойство Connection не инициализировано.

Comment: Что это значит?

Comment: Это означает, что соединение создать то создали, а открыть забыли. Почитайте [справку, там и пример есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Подправил код в button4. Теперь ошибки инициализации нет, ошибок вообще нет, но в бд содержимое ячейки не изменяется...никак не могу разобраться что же не так

Comment: Вы пример из справки смотрели? Там готовая функция для выполнения SQL есть, её пробовали?